# React Native iOS - fatal error: module 'GoogleMapsBase' not found

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

iOS build got failed due to `fatal error: module 'GoogleMapsBase' not found`
i followed this doc also https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md and used this package : https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps

These are the steps I have already done.

- cleaned the code in xcode
- took rebuild
- did react-native link react-native-maps
- pod install
- added the lines in AppDelegate.m

here is my Podfile

```
target 'ios_user' do
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'

  pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'BatchedBridge'
  ]

  pod 'GoogleMaps'  
  pod 'react-native-maps', path: '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: '../node_modules/react-native-maps'  
end
```

these are the dependencies in package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "0.49.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "validate.js": "^0.11.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution for this error.

**Do not link AND use cocoapods. Do one of those two :)**

ref : https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/1722#issuecomment-338962189

Answer (score 0):

If this is only happening in iOS probably you are missing the library added in the project. Sometimes link does not work 100% and you have to do some manual work. Can you check that Google Maps appears in the Library Section?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

Comment: sfratini i have done this already. the manual linking. is there any other maps available except airbnb

Answer (score 0):

version seems not compatible, you can update pod repo by `pod repo update` and remove your `Podfile.lock` then `pod install` again.

1. `cd /ios`
2. `rm -rf Podfile.lock`
3. `pod repo update`
4. `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an answer here just in case someone comes upon this question as well.

My issue was my share extension's Deployment Target did not match the workspace nor the Pods file. The project would build for Debug, and I could run the app on the simulator, but I was unable to Archive the app. Once I updated the Deployment Target for my share extension, I was able to deploy the app to the App Store.